# How to set custom longPress Gesture in UIWebView displaying only an image

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, ios8, uigesturerecognizer

I've set a custom LongPressGesture recognizer to an UIWebView in an universal single window application within `ViewDidLoad`:

```
//Add long tap gesture handler
longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
longPress.delegate = self;
[_webBrowser addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
```

`_webBrowser` is my UIWebView. This works fine as long as i tap on an empty page, or an area without a link or any other active area.

If the User opens a url (eg. follows a href) which only displays an image, the longPress gesture seems to be overridden by iOS and a magnifying glass comes up if i press long on the page.

Is there a safe way (technical & in belongings to apples pre release checks) to always have my longPressGesture-Recognizer called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this code u can deactivate the default action sheet:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{


//deactivate default action sheet
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.style.webkitTouchCallout='none';"];
```

}

but i am not shure why u see an magnifier glas when you make a long press on a link

Answer (score 1):

implement this method in UIGestureRecognizerDelegate.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
 {
     return YES;
 }
```

Then your long press gesture will work.

Also, for a image, the magnifying glass won't show up as well if you add this.